# How to intercept Magento from fetching local tax rate?

Tags: magento

My Magento site has a tax rate table on another server. So, the tax rates are not in Magento tax_calculation_rate table.

On the checkout page, I need to intercept Magento from getting the tax rate number (by number I meant the percentage, not the amount) from local database. All the calculation will still be done by Magento. I only need to fetch the tax rate number (based on customer's address), that's it.

I'm thinking either using **tax_rate_data_fetch** event or **sales_quote_collect_totals_before** event. Should I use an event/observer or Magento API to fetch the tax rate number from other server? The other server will provide the data in xml format after getting request from Magento.

Any hint of steps for what I should do to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you just update tax rates in the magento DB via import or script to match rates on second service?

Comment: Wish I could, but my client needs me to retrieve the tax percent on the fly from the tax server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Seems like tax_rate_data_fetch is the right event. Strikeiron module implements this to get tax rate for US and Canada." - Yu Tang, a Magento Tax Team developer. So check out [d/l the extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/strikeiron-extension.html)  the extension and code related to tax_rate_data_fetch.